# how would one run aws lambda locally (java) for testing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How would one run aws lambda locally (java) for testing.

I was able to find some information for node, but not for java.

Comment: Could you share what you found for node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using these docker images https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK there is no magic to actually triggering the lambda function locally. Take a look at: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model-req-resp.html
and
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-gs.html

Depending what your lambda code does you need to build the input and (possibly the context) and pass them into the function writing your own small test wrapper.

Unless you are doing this for unit testing it does not make sense to go through the trouble though. If you are doing this for testing you will probably need to mock out other external AWS services that your lambda might use.

Comment: My tool https://github.com/sportarchive/aws-lambda-python-local does Mock the context for you and even inject Cognito IdentityID so you can test unauthenticated calls.

Answer (score 4):

You can use AWS Toolkit for **Eclipse** if you want to perform local testing for Amazon Lambda functions, and build serverless applications in Amazon.

But since Aug 11, 2017, Amazon provides the AWS SAM Local, a CLI tool that allows us to locally test and debug our AWS Lambda functions. SAM Local supports Lambda functions written in Node.js, Java, and Python.

**Please vote** for implementing **Intellij IDEA** support for Amazon Lambda here:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-180070

Answer (score 3):

SAM Local - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/test-sam-local.html 
and 
docker-lambda - https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda have worked well for APIs that need only javaee and project sources.
I am still trying to figure out how to set to set the classpath to include the gradle dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of projects going on to run the entire AWS stack locally.

Java I believe the main option is [Localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack)

If you're on Javascript you can go [Serverless](https://serverless.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IntelliJ there is `aws-toolkit` - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11349-aws-toolkit/

It works very well, you can set environment variables etc. It will require you to have docker running on your local machine. Not very memory friendly though.

If you are using serverless, you can do `sls offline`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new upgrade for Lambda java test.

```
@Test 
public void testLoadEventBridgeEvent() throws IOException {
    // Given
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    InputStream eventStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("event.json");
    ScheduledEvent event = objectMapper.readValue(eventStream, ScheduledEvent.class);
    EventHandler<ScheduledEvent, String> handler = new EventHandler<>();
    
    // When
    String response = handler.handleRequest(event, contextMock);
    
    // Then
    assertThat(response).isEqualTo("something");
}
```

Please read this article
https://aws.amazon.com/cn/blogs/opensource/testing-aws-lambda-functions-written-in-java/?nc1=h_ls

Answer (score 0):

We use localstack to mock AWS.

Here is the docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.3"
    services:
      localstack:
        container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack_main}"
        image: localstack/localstack:1.2.0
        ports:
          - "4566:4566"            # LocalStack Gateway
        environment:
          - DEBUG=${DEBUG-}
          - PERSISTENCE=${PERSISTENCE-}
          - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=${LAMBDA_EXECUTOR-}
          - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

Now we have functional tests which creates a Lambda function on this localstack (mocked AWS)

```
 import software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.LambdaClient;
private LambdaClient lambdaClient;
private final AwsBasicCredentials awsCreds = AwsBasicCredentials.create("id", "key");
```

Below code creates a lambdaClient to interact with localstack

```
lambdaClient = LambdaClient.builder()
      .endpointOverride(URI.create("http://localhost:4566"))
      .region(Region.EU_WEST_1)
      .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds))
      .build();
```

Now using this lambdaClient, we can deploy the lambda function on localstack. We need a zip file of the code.

```
   createLambdaFunction(lambdaClient, "first-serverless-lambda", zipFilePath, "", "com.example.serverless.SampleLambda", new HashMap<>(Map.of("env-var-1","env-var1-val"));
```

And here is the implementation of `createLambdaFunction`

```
public static void createLambdaFunction(LambdaClient lambdaClient,
                                          String functionName,
                                          String filePath,
                                          String role,
                                          String handler,
 Map<String, String> config                                       ) {

    try {
      var waiter = lambdaClient.waiter();
      var is = new FileInputStream(filePath);
      var fileToUpload = SdkBytes.fromInputStream(is);

      lambdaClient.createFunction(builder -> builder.functionName(functionName)
        .description("Created by the Lambda Java API")
        .code(codeBuilder -> codeBuilder.zipFile(fileToUpload))
        .handler(handler)
        .runtime(Runtime.JAVA11)
        .environment(environmentBuilder -> environmentBuilder.variables(config))
        .role(role));
      
      waiter.waitUntilFunctionExists(builder -> builder.functionName(functionName)).matched();

    } catch (LambdaException | FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

References: https://github.com/localstack/localstack