# How do I run zipped file created for lambda function locally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle, aws-lambda

How do I run a zipped java file, created for lambda, locally?

When a zip is created by following the link
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-package.html

We can upload the zip to lambda for running application on it.

How do I run the zip if I need to test the functions locally.
By unzipping the same zipped file, I can see java classes compiled into *.class files.

When I ran `java MainClass` it is throwing

Error: Unable to initialize main class MainClass
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/redisson/client/codec/Codec

I am using redisson as a dependency here.

Note: I can create fatJar or other methods to test the function locally but I need to re use how lambda would run this zip.

I don't want to run the lambda function locally.

I want to run the actual code, using the same zip created from gradle zip task.

Question can be worded as "How do I run java application from zip. The zip is created from a gradle task"

I am using gradle to build and make zip file

Comment: This statement makes no sense: "I don't want to run the lambda function locally. I want to run the actual code, using the same zip, just like lambda runs the code." Lambda doesn't "run" a zip file. It unzips it, and then runs the code. There is no distinction between running your code locally, and running the unzipped code locally.

Comment: Right, lambda unzips and runs the code. How does that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After zipping the java application with https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html.

All we need is to unzip the zipped file and pass in location of jars as class path.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know that your Lambda must be run inside an execution environment providing an API (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-api.html).

You may use for this the RIE from https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-runtime-interface-emulator and the RIC from https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/tree/main/aws-lambda-java-runtime-interface-client.

As a summary, you need to use the RIE and RIC and unzip your lambda zip bundle in folder /test. Then you run your a command like this:

`aws-lambda-rie java -cp/test/*:/test/lib/*:<RIC libs> com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda <Your lambda handler>`

The call is then done with curl for example:

`url -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{}'`

I suggest you to take a look at my project https://microlam.io (which use maven and not gradle) that may help you build this with docker taking example of the Dockerfile I use for configuring the native compilation in `src/docker/native-config/Dockerfile`

If you are motivated you could add this to microlam :-)

Answer (score -1):

The only way to debug/test AWS lambdas locally is by using AWS SAM in debug mode

```
sam local invode -d <debug port, normally 5858> <function logical id>
```

You can't just run the jar file.  Have a look at the aws sam documentation. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-debugging.html

Comment: Maybe I worded things wrong. I don't want to run the lambda function locally. I want to run the actual code, using the same zip, just like lambda run the code.

Comment: AWS SAM is not the _only_ way to test a Lambda function locally. Depending on the language and frameworks you are using, there are usually several ways to test a function locally.

Comment: @MarkB - Could you please explain how else a Java (since that's what's being asked about) lambda would be tested? Aside from junit testing, by running the code in the same manner that lambda would run it that is.

Comment: You could use the `aws-lambda-java-tests` library, as recommended by AWS https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/testing-aws-lambda-functions-written-in-java/ It's also fairly trivial to write test harnesses for this sort of thing yourself. People were writing Java Lambda functions and testing them locally for years before the AWS SAM product even existed.

Comment: Right, those are unit tests, which was clearly not what the question is asking about.

Comment: Also all the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259952/how-would-one-run-aws-lambda-locally-java-for-testing